# Postgres/PostGIS spatial join returning null results

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, spatial-join, srid

I have 1.3 million points and 15 thousand polygons.

I'm trying to do a spatial join so I can find out how many points intersect with each polygon. Ultimately, I'll add up the values in some columns in the point data by each polygon.

So the point data is PCD4 and the polygon data is HCBG.
I've verified that both tables have the same SRID. 
I tried this fairly simple spatial join query but the results are a null set which makes no sense!

```
select geoid, id
from public."PCD4"
join public."HCBG"
ON ST_Intersects(public."HCBG".geom, public."PCD4".geom)
group by id, public."PCD4".geom, geoid`
```

I've tried limiting the query to a single polygon but that also nulled out. 
I've checked the data in QGIS and there are definitely points in the polygons and specifically in the single test polygon I tried.

If I try to do the spatial join in QGIS, it errors out.

I've tested the integrity of the polygons. They're Census Tiger files and they checked out fine.

So I'm at a loss here. I'm sure the problem is something to do with the alignment of the data, either projection or something. But I am not sure how to troubleshoot it beyond checked for the SRID.

Comment: if you remove the public."PCD4".geom in the group by clause what happens? also if you had different SRID postgres would most likely tell you there are mixed SRIDs

Comment: If I remove the geom from the group by I get the same result.

Comment: try this...ST_Intersects(st_makevalid(public."HCBG".geom), st_makevalid(public."PCD4".geom))

Comment: ST_MakeValid shouldn't do anything in this case. I've run ST_IsValid on all the polygons and the points. There are no 'f' values for the returned query. So all my shapes and points are valid as is.

Comment: I am running your query now, just in case.

Comment: hmm this is very strange, its a very basic query and you say your data is valid.

Comment: I wonder if it is OK to group by something that you do not select - `public."PCD4".geom`

Comment: seems to work for me... which version of postgres / postgis? Also, do the layers overlap visually when loaded into QGIS? This is to rule out getting the x and y values wrong way round when importing the point layer. If I had a penny for every time I'd done that... ;-) Probably not an issue if this is contiguous USA but worth checking.

Comment: how did you import these layers into postgres?

Comment: @StevenKay  That's a good thing to check for. I'll go back through and look at that too.

Comment: So I have parcel data from the county I'm in. That's downloaded from the assessor's dept. I already found all the broken parcel shapes and removed them from my data. Then I took the centroid of each of those parcels to make the points data.

Comment: The HCBG stuff is Census Tiger shapefiles of blockgroups for my state. If I remember correctly I used the shp2psql tool to get it into Postgres.

Comment: okay and im assuming census is in 4269 or 4326. what was the original SRID of your parcel data? state plane?

Comment: `select ST_AsText(geom) from yourtable limit 1` and post one from each of your tables

Answer (score 1):

The more I use SQL, the more I find it simpler to break these queries down into their components, ie subqueries, instead of trying to do it all at once.
Let's start with a join to tag each point with the polygon it falls within.  I'm using the `st_covers` function for this as it takes into account points that fall on a polygon boundary.
I assign an alias to each table name to make them easier to reference in the query.  I am not sure which ID goes with which layer, so I will make up names.  Simply substitute with the correct ones.

```
SELECT pcd4.fid,
       hcbg.gid,
       pcd4.geom
FROM public."PCD4" pcd4
JOIN public."HCBG" hcbg
  ON st_covers(hcbg.geom, pcd4.geom)
```

This selects the ID of each point, and assigns the ID of the containing polygon.  This can now be used as a `WITH` query for another `SELECT` query.

```
WITH pcd4_poly AS (
  SELECT pcd4.fid,
         hcbg.gid
  FROM public."PCD4" pcd4
  JOIN public."HCBG" hcbg
    ON st_covers(hcbg.geom, pcd4.geom)
)
SELECT hcbg.gid,
       count(pcd4_poly.fid),
       hcbg.geom
FROM public."HCBG" hcbg
WHERE hcbg.gid = pcd4_poly.gid
GROUP BY hcbg.gid
```

This query selects the ID and geometry of each polygon.  The `WITH` command runs that select query to select the ID of each point, tagged with the ID of each polygon.  When you select these together, it creates a one to many selection of polygons to points.  Grouping on the polygon ID with a count of the point ID gives you the summary of point records per polygon that you are looking for.

I admit this may not be the most efficient way of doing it.  It does, however, give you a process where it is easy to test each component to ensure they work separately, before putting them together.

To address what was at issue with your query, I notice you include what I think are the IDs from both layers, plus the point layer geometry in your `GROUP BY` clause.  Since you are doing an intersection, there is no need to have a group clause as you aren't performing any aggregate operation in the `SELECT` query.  The first part of your query would suffice.  You may have had a `NULL` result simply because it was trying to display 1.3 million points.

```
select geoid, id
from public."PCD4"
join public."HCBG"
ON ST_Intersects(public."HCBG".geom, public."PCD4".geom)
```